# Use Google Sheets to Import Data from API without Script

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using IMPORTDATA to import data from an API.
e.g. `=IMPORTDATA("https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/EUR/")`

Unfortunately I have to click the cells everytime I open the spreadsheet to get the new Data from the API.
Is there any way to have the spreadsheet refresh itself every hour or so to get the new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want any script, then you can go to your **Spreadsheet** -> **FILE** -> **Spreadsheet settings** -> **Calculation** then make it `on change every hour`.

For more information, check this [page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092981?visit_id=1-636216206741708936-3122431981&hl=en&rd=2).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: It says in the docu, this will only work for date and rand functions. Are you sure this works? Unfortunately in my example I can't really test this...